# Laravel - validation rule to check field exists in the database and a column belong to the same row is set to a specified value

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm passing an array of contacts to a controller to be deleted. While validating the request, I need to make sure that the contact that is being requested to delete is not set as the preferred contact. (`is_preferred = 1`)

Data I'm sending :

```
[
   contacts => [
      [contact => '9874563214'],
      ['contact' => '8745632145'],
   ]
]
```

This is how I'm validating the data in the extended `FormRequest` class.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'contacts.*.contact' => 'bail|regex:/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/',
    ];
}
```

This is what I have coded, is the correct way ? How do I pass current contact being evaluated to (`where("contact_no", xxx)`)

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'contacts.*.contact' => 'bail|regex:/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/|exists:user_contact,contact_no|
        Rule::unique("user_contact")->where(function ($query) { $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where("contact_no", XXX )->where("is_preferred", 1);}',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can using custom query in your Request file.
For Example;

```
public function rules() {
    $roles['contacts.*.contact'] = [
        'bail',
        'regex:/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/',
        'exists:user_contact,contact_no',
         Rule::unique("user_contact")
             ->where(function ($query) { 
                 $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                 ->where("contact_no", XXX )->where("is_preferred", 1);
             })
    ];
    return $roles;
}
```

If you want use any field value in your query, you can pass field value via `use` keyword to Closure function. Here we will post `YOM` instance which is this means you can use it as `Request` so you can access all request parameters.

For Example;

```
public function rules() {
    $roles['contacts.*.contact'] = [
        'bail',
        'regex:/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/',
        'exists:user_contact,contact_no',
         Rule::unique("user_contact")
             ->where(function ($query) use ($this) {
                 $contacts = array_values($this->contacts);
                 $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                 ->whereIn("contact_no", $contacts )->where("is_preferred", 1);
             })
    ];
    return $roles;
}
```

A advice, you should not use query in your validation Request file directly, because it not looks like nice.

You can use [Custom Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules) instead of inline query. It will be very clear.

Comment: How do I pass the current contact being evaluated to where("contact_no", XXX)  .  "XXX" need to be replaced with the current contact in the contacts array that is being evalutated.

Comment: Can you give detail?

Comment: Firstly  "$this->contact_no"  doesn't refers to anything. It doesn't points to the current contact being evaluated.  I tried  dd($this->contacts) it show me  (array:1 [ 3 => array:1 ["contact" => "9758885005"]]) . How do I know the index number ?

Comment: secondly, this is the query that is getting generated  :  select count(*) as aggregate from `user_contact` where `contact` = 8868967012 and (`user_id` = 1 and `contact_no` is null and `is_preferred` = 1))".   As you can see there is a where 'contact' = 8868967012 that is getting added automatically.

Comment: I used as example it $this->contact_no. :) If you post contact number as array, you can use whereIn('contact_no', $this->contacts); But you may make require manipulated in query. You have to work on :)

Comment: Edited my my answer. Check please.

Comment: Thanks that solved the first issue, second issue still exists there.

Comment: What is your second issue?

Comment: check the 7th comment.

Comment: How to you print this query? I don't understand.

Comment: I can see the query that is being generated in the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187102/discussion-between-fgdeveloper-and-tintin).